# Magento Add custom links to nav menu

Tags: php, html, magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I need to know the **easiest way to add menu within the magento nav menu**.
Is there ane **FREE** extension that can provide the functionality to add custom links to nav menu **without making any Rewrites from Magento**?

I already made a research but without success. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried MegaMenu master? Is a free extension and can be found on GitHub.

Comment: That's a good extension but unfortunately they don't provide magento admin settings. So you need to edit code to add new links. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Magento ce 1.7+ you can use the event `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before`.
In version 1.7+ the top menu is treated as a container where you can place any link you want.
Here is a small example. Your observer can look like this:

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer {
    public function addItemsToTopmenuItems($observer) {
        $menu = $observer->getMenu();
        $tree = $menu->getTree();
        $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();

        $nodeId = 'some-node-id';
        $data = array(
            'name' => Mage::helper('[module]')->__('Title goes here'),
            'id' => $nodeId,
            'url' => Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action'),
            'is_active' => ($action == 'module_controller_action')
        );
        $node = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
        $menu->addChild($node);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and the event declaration in config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
            <observers>
                <[module]>
                    <class>[module]/observer</class>
                    <method>addItemsToTopmenuItems</method>
                </[module]>
            </observers>
        </page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

This will add an item after the categories.
To add items at the beginning or middle of the menu [check this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7329/146)

Note: Of course this is an example. You can make your module to support adding links through the config panel or anything else that you can thing of.